# Flutter complicated Responsive UI

Tags: flutter, user-interface, responsive

I am programming a mobile app and I got the design for the tablet version but I could not figure out how to do it the right way. I know how to do a simple master/details screen but the screens here are more complicated as in the images below. The screens are linked but I don't want the left (fixed) screen to be rebuilt every time I click on its buttons or on the buttons in the right screen (like separated windows or panels in a desktop application). Please give me an advice on how to achieve this task.

[image: mobile design]

[image: tablet design]

I already have a class to manage the responsive feature of the app:

```
import 'package:chifa_pro/widgets/drawer.dart';
import 'package:chifa_pro/widgets/myAppBar.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class Responsive extends StatefulWidget {
  final Widget mobile;
  final Widget tablet;
  final Widget desktop;

  const Responsive({
    Key key,
    @required this.mobile,
    @required this.tablet,
    @required this.desktop,
  }) : super(key: key);

  static bool isMobile(BuildContext context) =>
      MediaQuery.of(context).size.width < 650;

  static bool isTablet(BuildContext context) =>
      MediaQuery.of(context).size.width < 1194 &&
      MediaQuery.of(context).size.width >= 650;

  static bool isDesktop(BuildContext context) =>
      MediaQuery.of(context).size.width >= 1194;

  @override
  _ResponsiveState createState() => _ResponsiveState();
}

class _ResponsiveState extends State<Responsive> {
  final GlobalKey<ScaffoldState> scaffoldKeyResponsive =
      GlobalKey<ScaffoldState>();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return LayoutBuilder(
      key: UniqueKey(),
      builder: (context, constraints) {
        if (constraints.maxWidth >= 1194) {
          return SafeArea(
              child: Scaffold(
                  appBar: MyAppBar(
                    'My App',
                  ),
                  body: widget.desktop));
        }

        if (constraints.maxWidth >= 650 && constraints.maxWidth < 1194) {
          return SafeArea(
              child: Scaffold(
                  appBar: MyAppBar(
                    'My App',
                  ),
                  drawer: AppDrawer(),
                  body: widget.tablet));
        } else {
          return widget.mobile;
        }
      },
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: If you seperate you widgets into smaller widgets, there won't be extra rebuild.

Comment: Maybe this feature can help you: https://pub.dev/packages/auto_route#nested-navigation .

Comment: The screens are already on separate stateful widgets. I know I can put them in a row but I don't know how to keep track of hierarchy. I click on screen 1 button on the left and I get details on screen 2 on the right. Then I click on screen 2 I get screen 3 (list of elements) always on the right (screen 1 is fixed on the left) then I click on one screen 3 element and I get screen 4 which is details of the element in screen 3 list.